# Wordpress multisite with same contents

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Trying to accomplish the following. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

1. I have multiple domain names (e.g., site1.com, site2.com, site3.com).
2. I need each domain to display the same content
3. But show a different wordpress theme.Plugins are same...etc

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

With regards to accessing the same site over different domains; although there may be recommendations against it as a general practice, you can add the following lines to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

With that, you're basically saying to Wordpress 'treat whatever domain that's pointing this way as my base URL'.

For switching themes accordingly, you could try something like this in your `functions.php` (untested):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'site2.com') !== FALSE) {
    add_filter('stylesheet', 'siteTwoTemplate');
    add_filter('template', 'siteTwoTemplate');
}

function siteTwoTemplate() {
    $themeToGrab =  'site2theme';

    $themeList = get_themes();

    foreach ($themeList as $theme) {
        if ($theme['Name'] == $themeToGrab) {
            return $theme['Stylesheet'];
        }
    }   
}
```

There may well be more efficient/safer means of achieving this, but it should do what you're after.